# PHP's copy() fails when executed from Apache, why?

Tags: php, apache, powershell, server

I'm copying  a file from `$source` to `$destination`.

If I execute `copy($source, $destination)` from PowerShell, it works.

If I call this `copy($source, $destination)` from Apache, it complains `copy(...): failed to open stream: Permission Denied.`

I am able to open up explorer and copy and paste file manually. I am using PHP 7.1, Apache 2.4 on Windows Server 2012R2.

Why is this happening? Could someone provide an insight?

Comment: You know what is __permission__?

Comment: if you use the power shell, php uses the same user you're logged in as. apache uses a different user (usually www or www-data or something)

Comment: @u_mulder target folder's properties shows, all users has 'Allow Write'.

Comment: @Jakumi, I'm using Windows Server 2012R2.

Comment: I believe the php/apache config has some setting that says, which user is used when executing php scripts. this can very much differ from your user account, even on windows (and it very much should, because you can do so much more probably than what the webserver should be able to do)

Comment: @Jakumi Thanks for the hint. You're right. The Apache is running as a different user than the one shown in Local Services. I added a comment to the answer below. It is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If run under Windows Apache already has all the permissions it needs, as it runs under the LocalSystem account, which has extensive read/write access to local paths. This is inherited by PHP and the scripts it runs.

If there is a problem then –

- The additional file permissions that have been set up afterwards are at fault (check Windows Event viewer).
- The configuration has been incorrectly edited, such as the: WP upload path settings, php.ini temp folder location + upload settings, etc.
- The Apache Service ‘Log On’ account has been changed from “LocalSystem” to something else (check Service’s Properties).
- Possibly PHP’s open_basedir setting has been enabled in VirtualHost or .htaccess and is restricting the paths PHP can access.
- Or there are internal PHP errors (check the website’s HTTP and PHP error logs).

**EDIT**

Since it is sugggested i add this solution possibility if you are stuck at point 3:

- Create a user with extensive file permissions and change Apaches service to run under that user. I strongly suggest not to use the system admin user (or any admin user) profile for this.

Comment: +1 for the extensive list. I went through them all. All seems well. Apache error log only tells me; `copy(...): failed to open stream: Permission Denied.` I don't think Windows Server has a concept of chmod?

Comment: I went through your list again! I solved the problem. I stopped at point 3. I changed the LocalSystem to use my user name explicitly (I have admin rights). And it solved the problem. If you update your answer to include this suggestion, I'll give you a tick! Since you helped in the right direction, I think I better let you have the tick after your update.

Comment: @ikel you probably should not let apache run as admin ... really ... you should not! you should change the file permissions so that apache can access it.

Comment: @Jakumi, folder permission is ok. I have same folder permission as the 'real' admin of the server. Changing LocalSystem to use my own username solves it. I could have created a new user with less privileges to restrict Apache access, but I don't think I am allowed to do so by our 'real' admin. I'll let it be as it is for now, as I have a tight deadline to meet. If time and 'real' admin permit, I'll revisit the problem using a user with less privileges to run Apache.